# Merge conflict when merging back to master

Tags: git, maven, merge

I have the following scenario in Git:
2 branches

- develop
- master

All the development is done on `develop`. On `develop` we will create a new `snapshot` branch when we want to create a snapshot. On this `snapshot` branch we will create a `release` branch when we want to release it.

After a `release` we merge the release branch back with its `snapshot` branch and we merge the `release` branch with the `master`.

During a release we change the version with `mvn:set` in the pom.xml.
This process works fine except the last step. I get sometimes conflicts with the merge between `release` and `master`.

And example: I create a release and merge with master = ok. Then I do a hotfix on my snapshot branch (add some file) and release again. The new release will merge again with the snapshot but the merge with my master has a conflict but only on the `pom.xml`:

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Auto-merging xxx/pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in xxx/pom.xml
```

The version inside `pom.xml` is different of course (version of `master` needs to  be replaced by version of `release` branch). But this is also the case for the merge between `release` and `snapshot` branch where it's always working.

The code is pretty basic for this merge. It's nearly the same code as the merge between the `release` branch and the `support` branch. where it always works.

```
echo "merge Release branch with master branch";
git checkout master;
git merge REL-1.0.0;
git push origin master;
```

What am I missing here?

This is the content of my pom.xml after an unsuccesful merge where 1.0.1 needs to be replaced by 1.1.0

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <version>REL-1.0.1</version>
=======
    <version>REL-1.1.0</version>
>>>>>>> REL-1.1.0
```

Comment: Why merge the release branch in master? How I do is if there is any regression introduced in the release branch, I cherry pick the commit from the master and put it on the release branch. The release branch is created from the latest master.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve this conflict before commit and push, so you have to do something like 
    
    `echo "merge Release branch with master branch";
    git checkout master;
    git merge REL-1.0.0;
    git mergetool --tool=kdiff3
    git commit
    git push origin master;`